# C "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error on a function that returns an int

Tags: c, function, struct

I have the following code and am getting

"error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

int ab = findActiveBlock();"

I would understand this error if findActiveBlock was set to void but it is returning an int? Please help

```
void updateActiveBlock() {

    int ab = findActiveBlock();
    //code using ab//
}

int findActiveBlock() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKCOUNT; i++) {
        if(blocks[i].active) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

additional info: this is C, "blocks[]" is an array of structs.

Comment: thats because you need to declare findActiveBlock before you call it.

Comment: @pm100: Unlikely. Those compilers that woudn't reject the code outright, would normally assume that an undeclared function returns `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 4):

I would make a wild guess that your `findActiveBlock` is actually pre-declared somewhere above as a `void`-returning function. You simply forgot to update that declaration to make it match the definition.

P.S. As an additional side note: `()` parameter lists is an obsolescent feature in C. For functions that have no parameters, prefer to use `(void)` in their declarations.

Comment: that was it! thank you! I'm still getting used to header files and I always forget to update them.. thanks !!

Answer (score -2):

Just a stab in the dark, but is *.active a function? If so it would need parentheses.

```
 int findActiveBlock() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKCOUNT; i++) {
        if(blocks[i].active()) {   //added parentheses to active
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There are no member functions in C. Yes, it could be a function pointer, but that wouldn't make any sense in the context.

Comment: And if it were a function pointer, it would not be a void value that should be ignored. It would be a pointer-to-function value.